# Stripe payment gateway create recurring payment using PayumBundle

Tags: php, symfony, stripe-payments, payum

I am using [PayumBundle](https://github.com/Payum/PayumBundle) to integrate Stripe payment gateway to my symfony2 application. 
i can create a successful direct payment, however i cannot create a recurring one. as the documentation of the bundle very poor.

My question is how to implement recurring payment for a customer using PayumBundle or any similar one.

Comment: The support of Stripe recurring payment is not added to Payum. I can do that for you or you can do it yourself (send a PR (; ).

Comment: excuse me, what's PR?

Comment: Sorry, By PR I meant Pull Request.

Comment: @MaksimKotlyar check my answer for the question, would be grateful for your feedback

Comment: @MaksimKotlyar, PR:  https://github.com/Payum/PayumBundle/issues/249

Comment: The status problem must be fixed by this PR: https://github.com/Payum/Payum/pull/331. Try to upgrade payum/payum

Comment: @MaksimKotlyar, Yes it got fixed thanks, any news about the recurring payment for stripe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manage to do a small combination between PayumBundle & Stripe-php as following:

```
/**
 * @Extra\Route(
 *   "/prepare_checkout",
 *   name="mycom_stripe_prepare_checkout"
 * )
 *
 * @Extra\Template("MYCOMStripeBundle:PurchaseExamples:prepareCheckout.html.twig")
 */
public function prepareCheckoutAction(Request $request) {
    $paymentName = 'subscribe_guardia_via_stripe_checkout';

    $storage = $this->getPayum()->getStorage('MYCOM\PaymentBundle\Entity\PaymentDetails');

    /** @var $details PaymentDetails */
    $details = $storage->create();
    $details["amount"] = 85 * 100;
    $details["currency"] = 'USD';
    $details["description"] = "Bi-Annual Subs.";

    if ($request->isMethod('POST') && $request->request->get('stripeToken')) {
        // create a new customer and assign a plan for him
        \Stripe::setApiKey($this->container->getParameter('stripe.secret_key'));
        $customer = \Stripe_Customer::create([
                    'description' => 'amr samy',
                    'source' => $request->request->get('stripeToken'),
                    'plan' => 'C1',
        ]);

        $details["customer"] = $customer->id;
        $storage->update($details); // presist the customer and the payment


        $captureToken = $this->getTokenFactory()->createToken(
                $paymentName, $details, 'mycom_subscription_create_stripe_recurring_payment'
        );

        return $this->redirect($captureToken->getTargetUrl());
    }

    return array(
        'publishable_key' => $this->container->getParameter('stripe.publishable_key'),
        'model' => $details,
        'paymentName' => $paymentName
    );
}
```

The only issue i am facing is if use createCaptureToken() it shows Checkout Payment Form again, hence i used createToken() instead, however gain i face another issue which is the status of the transaction is new.

Comment: Try to do a forward instead $this->redirect($captureToken->getTargetUrl());  Or save the stripeToken to the details.